# How to properly inject services into other services

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony-services

I'm trying to figure out how to inject Drupal services into a custom service class. The class in question is my `MenuService` which builds an associative array of menu items which will be encoded to json and sent as a response for my custom REST endpoint ( `/api/menu/{menu_name}` ).

As a part of that, I need three classes:

`\Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManager`

`\Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeParameters`

`\Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkTree`

Any help on tracking down the `MenuTreeParameters` service would be helpful. I don't see it on [this list](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/services). If it's not a defined service, can it be injected?

*Note: Made some edits as I answered most of my own question*

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I think I figured it out. It should look something like this:

I couldn't find the service name anywhere for `MenuTreeParameters` so it's omitted in the examples for now.

I setup my menu service in `rest_api.services.yml`

```
services:
  rest_api.menu_service:
    class: Drupal\rest_api\Services\MenuService
    arguments: ['@path.alias_manager', '@menu.link_tree']
```

And created my service:

```
namespace Drupal\rest_api\Services;

use \Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkTree;
use \Drupal\Core\Path\AliasManager;
use \Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeParameters;

class MenuService {

  protected $aliasManager;

  public function __construct(AliasManager $aliasManager, MenuLinkTree $menuTree) {
    $this->aliasManager = $aliasManager;
    $this->menuTree = $menuTree;
    $this->items = array();
  }
```